# How do I use curl request to create an Azure Pipeline from yaml file using the CLI?

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, azure-automation, azure-pipelines-yaml

I created a repo in azure, I created a bash file that cloned the repo from my CLI using:

$curl git clone https://username@dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/reponame

which cloned the repo. My challenge now is automating the yaml file I have saved in my local machine, such that when I push, it goes to the remote repo and builds automatically. I would appreciate your ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have not created an azure pipeline for your repo, then push the yaml file wont trigger a pipeline, since it doesnot exist.

- How do I use curl request to create an Azure Pipeline from yaml file using the CLI?

If you intend to create your azure pipeline using curl request. You can call [Build Definition Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) restful api to create a pipeline via cli.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1
```

See below script example:

Check here to get a [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

You can call [repository list rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the id of your repository. You can also get the repository id for the UI (go to **Project Settings**--> **Repositories** under **Repo**--> **select** the your repository-->You will see the repository id in the **address bar** `repositoryId=96a56858-..-...`)

```
curl -X POST \
-u username:personalaccesstoken https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1 \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "name" : "MyPipelineName";
    "repository" : {
        "url" : "<the-https-link-to-my-Git-repo>";
        "defaultBranch" : "refs/heads/master";
        "id" : "Id of the repository";
        "type" : "TfsGit";
    };
    "process" : {
        "yamlFilename": "path to/my-pipeline.yml";
        "type" : 2;
    };
    "path": "\A New Folder";
    "type" : "build";
}'
```

You can also create azure pipeline from your azure devops project UI portal.  Please check the detailed steps [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition). Since you already have your yaml file. You can choose  `Existing Azure Pipeline YAML file` during the setting up wizard. See below:

[image]

To enable triggerring your pipeline automatically after your created your pipeline via above methods. You need to define triggers in your yaml file.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#triggers) for more information.

For below example: every push to master branch will trigger build on master branch.

```
trigger:
- master
```

Note: yaml file must exist in the branch to trigger a build against this branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure DevOps CLI:

1. [Store the personal access token in environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#use-environment-variables) (or other way)
2. Create a new repo in your DevOps organization by calling [az repos create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-repos-create)
3. Push local git repository to that repo (#2) by calling **git push** command
4. Create a new yaml pipeline by calling [az pipelines create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-create)

Then the related build will be ran.